# How to set MONO_PATH on OSX System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (remote SQLServer db)

Tags: c#, sql-server, macos, mono, xsp4

Scenario:
I run `xsp4 --port 9000` from the command line in the directory of my .net app.

I navigate to `localhost:9000` and see this:
[image: When I navigate to local host I get this.]

Back on the console I see this:

```
Path '/Default.aspx' built successfully, but a compilation exception has been thrown for other files:
Compiler errors:
(0,0) : warning CS1685: The predefined type `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncStateMachineAttribute' is defined multiple times. Using definition from `mscorlib.dll'
(0,0) : error : /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.3/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous warning)
(0,0) : error : /Users/liveclass/Documents/changeyourenergy/Bin/System.Runtime.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous warning)
(0,0) : warning CS1685: The predefined type `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberNameAttribute' is defined multiple times. Using definition from `mscorlib.dll'
(0,0) : error : /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.3/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous warning)
(0,0) : error : /Users/liveclass/Documents/changeyourenergy/Bin/System.Runtime.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous warning)
(0,0) : warning CS1685: The predefined type `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumberAttribute' is defined multiple times. Using definition from `mscorlib.dll'
(0,0) : error : /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.3/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous warning)
(0,0) : error : /Users/liveclass/Documents/changeyourenergy/Bin/System.Runtime.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous warning)
(0,0) : warning CS1685: The predefined type `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePathAttribute' is defined multiple times. Using definition from `mscorlib.dll'
(0,0) : error : /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.3/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous warning)
(0,0) : error : /Users/liveclass/Documents/changeyourenergy/Bin/System.Runtime.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous warning)

Exception thrown:
System.Web.Compilation.CompilationException: : /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.3/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous warning)
...
```

I tried:

- Seeing if there is a MONO_PATH issue in case mono is using .net4.5 as opposed to 4.0 like I want.  I noticed [this issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626577/the-assembly-mscorlib-dll-was-not-found-or-could-not-be-loaded), but am unable to figure out how to set the MONO_PATH correctly on a Mac (as I haven't used one since 1986). The instructions seem to apply to ubuntu.
- I noticed that there is a `mono --config FILE` option, however, I can't seem to find anything in the latest docs that tells me how to create a config file and actually use the option.
- Running `export MONO_MANAGED_WATCHER=disabled` based on [this article](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2118). This fixed a different issue.

Comment: try running this in your project directory:

`MONO_PATH=<your_mono_path> xsp4 --port 9000`

Comment: What do I put in the `<your_mono_path>` part?

Comment: based on the error you got, i'd try `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.3/lib/mono/4.5/`

but i'm not sure that's going to solve the issue...seems unrelated to having `MONO_PATH` set to me...that said, give it a shot & see if it gets you any "further"